# Playing protected music in a UWP app

Tags: uwp, windows-10, media, drm

I am in the process of deciding to write a media player app in UWP.
I want to be able to stream music from Groove through the API which I can do already.
But I also want to be able to play music that a user might have already downloaded through the Groove App for offline listening.
Does anyone know if this is possible?
I have played around with it a bit and can get local MP3s to play but anything DRM protected gives an error. I didn't expect it to just let me play it but I did think I would be able to authenticate myself and then play it?

Answer (score 0):

> But I also want to be able to play music that a user might have already downloaded through the Groove App for offline listening. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I think if you didn’t know how to decrypt Groove’s audio file, it’s impossible.

> I didn't expect it to just let me play it but I did think I would be able to authenticate myself and then play it?

Yes. If you know key material (including private keys, content keys, and any other key material etc.), you can either use a PlayReady object with multiple key identifiers (KeyIDs), or use content decryption model data (CDMData) with multiple KeyIDs.

Please read “[PlayReady Encrypted Media Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/playready-encrypted-media-extension#whats-new-in-playready-encrypted-media-extension)” for more details.

“[PlayReady sample Universal Windows Apps for Windows 10](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PlayReady-samples-for-124a3738)” for your reference.